# Javascript Toggle class working but class not effective in element in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I frequently get these particular type of error in my code constantly which I will add a toggle function to the `classList` of an element with JavaScript and the code will toggle the class if I checked using the inspect element, but the class won't be effective to the element I add it to....

NOW MY PROBLEM IS :

In the code below at the media queries `(max-width: 605px)`, I am trying to make a dropdown navigation. I added `display:none` to the `#navbarp` in the CSS and I added another class `.open #navbarp { display:flex}`, and I used the JavaScript to toggle the `.open` class. The JavaScript was toggling the class `.open` to the `#navbarp` but the CSS class wasn't effective -- the `display: none` wasn't changing to `display:flex`.

Please go to the link below to check the code

https://codepen.io/enipx/pen/zegJeP

```js
var iconBtn = document.getElementById('icon-p');
var navbarp = document.getElementById('navbarp')

function openNav() {
  iconBtn.classList.toggle('click');
  navbarp.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* ==== NAVBAR */

#navbar {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #E5DDB3, #F7F1CF);
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  align-items: center;
}


/* ==== NAVBAR ICON */

#navbar #icon-p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

#navbar #icon-p:hover span {
  background-color: #333;
}

#icon-p span {
  width: 52px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  background-color: gray;
  transition: .4s;
}

.click .icon-1 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(9px, 7px);
}

.click .icon-2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.click .icon-3 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(9px, -7px);
}


/* ==== NAVBAR ELEMENT */

#navbarp {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 80px;
}

#navbarp .navbarpli {
  padding: 10px 25px;
}

#navbarp .navbarpli a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: gray;
  transition: .7s;
}

#navbarp .navbarpli a:hover {
  color: #333;
}


/* ==== NAVBAR DROPDOWN */

#dropdown {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #F7F1CF;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  display: none;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: .1s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(.9);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

#dropdown li {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: -40px;
  padding: 15px 10px;
}

#dropdown li:hover {
  background-color: #E2DCBB;
}

#dropdownBtn:hover #dropdown {
  display: block;
}


/* ==== media 910px */

@media (max-width: 910px) {
  #navbarp {
    margin-right: 30px;
  }
  #navbar #icon-p {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #navbarp {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  #navbar #icon-p {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  #navbarp .navbarpli {
    padding: 10px 20px;
  }
  #navbarp .navbarpli a {
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }
}


/* ==== media 700px */

@media (max-width: 706px) {
  #navbarp {
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  #navbar #icon-p {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  #navbarp .navbarpli {
    padding: 10px 18px;
  }
  #navbarp .navbarpli a {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}


/* ==== media 605px */

@media (max-width: 605px) {
  #navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #navbarp {
    flex-direction: column;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #E5DDB3, #F7F1CF);
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .open #navbarp {
    display: flex;
  }
  #navbarp .navbarpli {
    padding: 20px 0px;
  }
  #navbarp .navbarpli a {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  #navbar #icon-p {
    margin: 0px;
    margin: 12px 0;
  }
  #dropdown {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    right: 30%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div id="icon-p" onclick="openNav()">
    <span class="icon-1"></span>
    <span class="icon-2"></span>
    <span class="icon-3"></span>
  </div>
  <ul id="navbarp">
    <li class="navbarpli"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="navbarpli"><a href="#">Explore</a></li>
    <li class="navbarpli"><a href="#">Filter</a></li>
    <li class="navbarpli" id="dropdownBtn"><a href="#">Discover</a>
      <ul id="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">By Age</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">By User</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">By Name</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">By State</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navbarpli"><a href="#">Affiliate</a></li>
    <li class="navbarpli"><a href="#">More</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your selector should be `#navbarp.open`, not `.open #navbarp`.

Comment: @astonearachnidyeah, the class was toggling but the #navbarp .open is not adding the display:flex back to the code

Comment: there shouldn't be a space between `#navbarp` and `.open`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Change `.open #navbarp` to `#navbarp.open` (no space between `#navbarp` and `.open`). The former targets an element with id `navbarp` whose *parent* has the class `.open`. Using the latter (with no space) targets the element with both the ID and the class.
- Remove the `height: 0` and the `overflow: hidden`. These are making the elements disappear, even though `display: flex` is being applied. You shouldn't need them, because you have `display: none` which makes them totally disappear when they are supposed to be hidden.

```js
var iconBtn = document.getElementById('icon-p');
var navbarp = document.getElementById('navbarp')

function openNav() {
  iconBtn.classList.toggle('click');
  navbarp.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* ==== NAVBAR */

#navbar {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #E5DDB3, #F7F1CF);
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  align-items: center;
}


/* ==== NAVBAR ICON */

#navbar #icon-p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

#navbar #icon-p:hover span {
  background-color: #333;
}

#icon-p span {
  width: 52px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  background-color: gray;
  transition: .4s;
}

.click .icon-1 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(9px, 7px);
}

.click .icon-2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.click .icon-3 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(9px, -7px);
}


/* ==== NAVBAR ELEMENT */

#navbarp {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 80px;
}

#navbarp .navbarpli {
  padding: 10px 25px;
}

#navbarp .navbarpli a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: gray;
  transition: .7s;
}

#navbarp .navbarpli a:hover {
  color: #333;
}


/* ==== NAVBAR DROPDOWN */

#dropdown {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #F7F1CF;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  display: none;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: .1s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(.9);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

#dropdown li {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: -40px;
  padding: 15px 10px;
}

#dropdown li:hover {
  background-color: #E2DCBB;
}

#dropdownBtn:hover #dropdown {
  display: block;
}


/* ==== media 910px */

@media (max-width: 910px) {
  #navbarp {
    margin-right: 30px;
  }
  #navbar #icon-p {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #navbarp {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  #navbar #icon-p {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  #navbarp .navbarpli {
    padding: 10px 20px;
  }
  #navbarp .navbarpli a {
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }
}


/* ==== media 700px */

@media (max-width: 706px) {
  #navbarp {
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  #navbar #icon-p {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  #navbarp .navbarpli {
    padding: 10px 18px;
  }
  #navbarp .navbarpli a {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}


/* ==== media 605px */

@media (max-width: 605px) {
  #navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #navbarp {
    flex-direction: column;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #E5DDB3, #F7F1CF);
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
  }
  .open#navbarp {
    display: flex;
  }
  #navbarp .navbarpli {
    padding: 20px 0px;
  }
  #navbarp .navbarpli a {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  #navbar #icon-p {
    margin: 0px;
    margin: 12px 0;
  }
  #dropdown {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    right: 30%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div id="icon-p" onclick="openNav()">
    <span class="icon-1"></span>
    <span class="icon-2"></span>
    <span class="icon-3"></span>
  </div>
  <ul id="navbarp">
    <li class="navbarpli"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="navbarpli"><a href="#">Explore</a></li>
    <li class="navbarpli"><a href="#">Filter</a></li>
    <li class="navbarpli" id="dropdownBtn"><a href="#">Discover</a>
      <ul id="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">By Age</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">By User</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">By Name</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">By State</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navbarpli"><a href="#">Affiliate</a></li>
    <li class="navbarpli"><a href="#">More</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You are definitely correctly, actually i was suppose to remove the height and overflow in the code here...but my problem is the css combinator and thanks for it, i really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Selector in CSS part for the case when `#navbarp` has `open` class is written wrong. Currently, it is saying for **any children of the parent** that has class `open` and id equal `navbarp` apply this rule (like here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator). While the intent is that element over which rule should be applied, should contain has both id equal `navbarp` and class `open`.

So changing, `.open #navbarp` to `.open#navbarp` will fix an issue.

Comment: You are definitely correctly, my problem is the css combinator, will go through the link above. thanks alot, i really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use only one class for everything

```js
const The_NavBar = document.getElementById('navbar');

document.getElementById('icon-p').onclick = function()
{
  The_NavBar.classList.toggle('navOpen')
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* ==== NAVBAR */

#navbar {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #E5DDB3, #F7F1CF);
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  align-items: center;
}



/* ==== NAVBAR ICON */

#navbar #icon-p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

#navbar #icon-p:hover span {
  background-color: #333;
}

#icon-p span {
  width: 52px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  background-color: gray;
  transition: .4s;
}

#navbar.navOpen #icon-p span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(9px, 7px);
}

#navbar.navOpen #icon-p span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

#navbar.navOpen #icon-p span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(9px, -7px);
}

/* ==== NAVBAR ELEMENT */
#navbarp {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 80px;
}

#navbarp .navbarpli {
  padding: 10px 25px;
}

#navbarp .navbarpli a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: gray;
  transition: .7s;
}

#navbarp .navbarpli a:hover {
  color: #333;
}


/* ==== NAVBAR DROPDOWN */

#dropdown {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #F7F1CF;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  display: none;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: .1s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(.9);
  }

  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

#dropdown li {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: -40px;
  padding: 15px 10px;
}

#dropdown li:hover {
  background-color: #E2DCBB;
}

#dropdownBtn:hover #dropdown {
  display: block;
}


/* ==== media 910px */

@media (max-width: 910px) {
  #navbarp {
    margin-right: 30px;
  }

  #navbar #icon-p {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #navbarp {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }

  #navbar #icon-p {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }

  #navbarp .navbarpli {
    padding: 10px 20px;
  }

  #navbarp .navbarpli a {
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }
}


/* ==== media 700px */

@media (max-width: 706px) {
  #navbarp {
    margin-right: 5px;
  }

  #navbar #icon-p {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }

  #navbarp .navbarpli {
    padding: 10px 18px;
  }

  #navbarp .navbarpli a {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}


/* ==== media 605px */

@media (max-width: 605px) {
  #navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  #navbarp {
    flex-direction: column;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #E5DDB3, #F7F1CF);
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
  }

  #navbar.navOpen #navbarp {
    /*  .open#navbarp */
    display: flex;
  }

  #navbarp .navbarpli {
    padding: 20px 0px;
  }

  #navbarp .navbarpli a {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }

  #navbar #icon-p {
    margin: 0px;
    margin: 12px 0;
  }

  #dropdown {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    right: 30%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div id="icon-p">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <ul id="navbarp">
    <li class="navbarpli"><a href="#">Homes</a></li>
    <li class="navbarpli"><a href="#">Explore</a></li>
    <li class="navbarpli"><a href="#">Filter</a></li>
    <li class="navbarpli" id="dropdownBtn"><a href="#">Discover</a>
      <ul id="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">By Age</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">By User</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">By Name</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">By State</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navbarpli"><a href="#">Affiliate</a></li>
    <li class="navbarpli"><a href="#">More</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```